# Firebase error: The specified email address is invalid

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I keep getting the error "The specified email address is invalid" in my Ember-Firebase app, even if I created an account just to test log in.

I'm wondering if it has to do with the way I'm passing information as a string?

initializer/emberfire.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Firebase from 'firebase';


var session = Ember.Object.extend({
    ref : new Firebase("https://nutella.firebaseio.com"),

    addFirebaseCallback: function() {
        var session = this;
        var isNewUser = true;

        this.get("ref").onAuth(function(authData) {
            if (authData) {
                session.set("isAuthenticated", true);
            } else if (authData && isNewUser) {
                session.get("ref").child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
                    provider: authData.provider,
                    name: getName(authData)
                });
            } else {
                session.set("isAuthenticated", false);
            }
        });
    }.on("init"),

    createUser: function() {
        var session = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            session.get('ref').createUser({
                        name: "",
                        email: "",
                        password: ""
            },

            function(error, userData) {
                    if (userData) {
                        resolve(userData.uid);
                        session.set("isNewUser", true);
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
        });
    },
```

application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

var ref = new Firebase("https://nutella.firebaseio.com");

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        createUser: function() {
            var controller = this;
            controller.get('session').createUser().then(function(user) {
                }, function() {
                });
        },
```

I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string shouldn't be a problem. Here are a couple suggestions:

---

1. (This may be obvious, but...) It seems like you're passing empty strings to `createUser`:

```js
session.get('ref').createUser({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: ""
},
```

---

2. Assuming that you removed the strings from the code on purpose, there is also the fact that you're passing `Firebase.createUser()` an extra argument, `name`.

In the [`.createUser()` documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html), the arguments are listed as:

> `credentials` *Object*
>   An object containing email and password attributes corresponding to the new user account.
>
> `onComplete` *Function*
>   A callback function that will be called when the user account has been created. On failure, the first argument will be an Error object indicating the failure, with a machine-readable code attribute. On success, the first argument will be null, and the second argument will be an object containing attributes of the newly-created user, including the uid.

So, here is a revised version of your call to `createUser()`:

```
session.get('ref').createUser({
  email: "some@user.com",
  password: "somepassword123"
},
```

---

If that doesn't do it, can you provide more info - where (line number) are you getting that error?

*Hope that helps.*

Comment: @sunoceansand, were you able to try these out?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!! I have been traveling, just settling down so I will try them very soon and let you know. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome @sunoceansand! No rush, let us know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Not yet sorry--started working on other parts of the app, I'll let you know when we start working on it in a week! @sinan-bolel